# Check for unreachable at compilation time in Rust

Tags: rust, compile-time, unreachable-code

I have enum consisting of a few variants:

```rust
enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}
```

and i have a function, that has loop with if and match inside, all branches of which is diverging:

```rust
fn my_function() -> i32 {
  // some vars
  for ... in ... { // also may be `while` or `loop`
    // some code
    if some_condition {
      let foo: Foo = ...;
      match foo {
        Foo::A => { return 42 }
        Foo::B => { continue }
        Foo::C => {
          // do something with vars
          continue
        }
      }
      // this place is currently unreachable
      // and must **always** be **totally** unreachable
      // because the code after `if` must never execute in this(`some_condition`) case
    }
    // some code
  }
}
```

But with some future changes i may add new variant(s) to enum, so i want to check at **compilation** time, that that line is unreachable. I feel like this should be possible, but i don't know how to do it.

"Prior art":

- `unreachable!` doesn't work for me, because it's a runtime check and it takes a lot of time before this code executes plus no guarantee that it will hit this unreachable because of rng involved in process of getting there.
- `compile_error!` made for cfg flags, and in this case obviously gives error always, not depending of reachability of that place.
- `!`-type - not sure if it's possible to use never-type to solve this problem.

If only there existed something like `const_unreachable!` or `soft_compile_error!` which would fill this exact scenario of giving compile error if and only if there exists execution path that leads to it...

So what are possible solutions (including rust nightly and any features) to this problem?

Comment: What you're looking for is called an `else` clause and you can just put `// some code` that musn't run in the case `some_condition` is met into it. Alternatively you can just put `contiue` once after the `match`.

Comment: But the compiler already checks that, unless you add some wildcard branch into the `switch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On nightly, you can affect the result of your `match` to a variable with the "never" type:

```
#![feature(never_type)]

enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
}

fn main() {
    let x = Foo::A;
    let _: ! = match x {
        Foo::A => { println!("A"); return; }
        Foo::B => { println!("B"); /* Forgot `return` here */ }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=bac78b0307a3dce529d5690ba66640aa)

Gives:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:19
   |
12 | Foo::B => { println!("B"); /* Forgot `return` here */ }
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `!`, found `()`
   |
   = note:   expected type `!`
           found unit type `()`
```

As pointed out by @rodrigo, until the never type gets stabilized the same can be achieved on stable Rust using [`std::convert::Infallible`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/enum.Infallible.html):

```
enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
}

fn main() {
    let x = Foo::A;
    let _: std::convert::Infallible = match x {
        Foo::A => { println!("A"); return; }
        Foo::B => { println!("B"); /* Forgot `return` here */ }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=0bfcae36698e7d9e28d787e0243b7f75)

Comment: I was just writing this very same answer! But instead of `!`, in stable Rust you can write [`std::convert::Infallible`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/enum.Infallible.html).